# Twilio Mobile to Mobile Call

Tags: twilio

I am new to Twilio and I need some help on a specific scenario. I have been trying to find a solution for this for some time, but I haven't been able to do so.

I want to use a Twilio number from one mobile (A) to call another user on mobile (B). I want to do this in a manner where the call is initiated by the Twilio number and not by (A)'s phone number.

In other words, (A) dials a Twilio number from a mobile and Twilio in turn dials (B) and connects (B) with (A).

I have configured the Twilio phone number dialed by (A) to used a Twiml bin and I have used the Dial verb to dial (B) upon receiving the call from (A).

But the Dial verb adds user (B) to the call. USer (B) does not see the call coming from the Twilio number but from User (A). This is not what I was hoping to achieve.

First of all, I hope I have been able to explain the scenario properly.

IS the scenario possible?

IS it possible for me to get Twilio to dial another user's number when it receives a call from a user? (without using the dial verb in Twiml).

IS there any solution in the API?

Let me know your thoughts. Also, please feel free to ask for any clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you just need to supply a callerId parameter in your TwiML. Without one then Twilio will just use the incoming callers number as the caller ID, as you are currently experiencing.

You can use any Twilio number you have purchased or any number you have verified as the displayed caller ID. Your TwiML dial verb should look like this:

```
<Dial callerId="+15551231234">
<Number>+1555555555</Number>
</Dial>
```